# Твитнуть и ретвитнуть

Tags: выбор-слов

Как относиться к этим словам в русской локализации Твиттера? Это что-то вроде экзотизмов? Ведь твитнуть — это значит что-либо НАПИСАТЬ. Ретвитнуть — значит ПОДЕЛИТЬСЯ. Я не просто так выделил эти слова, ведь именно они имеют схожее значение с обсуждаемыми словами. Сейчас происходит активное усваивание этих слов русским обществом, Викисловарь даже имеет их в базе: [ретвитнуть](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D1%8C), [твитнуть](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D1%8C). Тот же твит — это запись. И как вы относитесь к локализации такого уровня? Мне этот вопрос кажется дискуссионным, потому что, с одной стороны, это неправильно, а с другой — у них была обязанность перевести специфичную лексику, придуманную компанией Twitter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Говорить о нормативности/ненормативности таких не совсем правильно. В истории русского языка было очень много слов, против которых выступали не только писатели, но и порой филологи, лингвисты. Но,тем не менее, эти слова прижились и вошли в литературный язык. Здесь надо помнить одну важную вещь: эти слова не просто появились как аналоги уже имеющихся русских слов, они возникли именно потому, что в них, так сказать, возникла потребность: за ними закреплено новое понятие: сообщение в социальной сети "Твиттер". В литературный язык эти слова, возможно, и не войдут, но в словаре в качестве интернет-жаргона они вполне могут закрепиться. Время покажет...

Answer (score 1):

Лингва россиянская грейтово чейнджнулась в ласт годы, и пока филологи/лингвисты воркуют над ее кодификацией, каждый имеет фридом юзать ту ее версию, которую он лайкает

При этом хорошо не впадать в крайний радикализм как американофильский (типа предыдущего абзаца), так и почвеннический "Хорошилище грядет из ристалища на позорище по гульбищу в мокроступах и с растопыркой" (я **знаю**, что это стилизация, и помню, что ей без малого два века), и что Сан "Наше Все" Сергеевич отмечал:

> ```
> Но панталоны, фрак, жилет,
> Всех этих слов на русском нет;
> А вижу я, винюсь пред вами,
> Что уж и так мой бедный слог
> Пестреть гораздо б меньше мог
> Иноплеменными словами,
> Хоть и заглядывал я встарь
> В Академический словарь.
> ```

Чрезмерная и избыточная англизация языка - явление ни разу не полезное, но "И это пройдет" (не в первый раз). Вопрос только в определении этой самой нормы.

Упираясь скрупулезно в смысл и точность определения терминов, надо отметить, что "чирикнуть" (твитнуть) не совсем точно определяется родным "написать" (т.к "написать твиттер-соообщение" имеет пресуппозицию "в чириканье не больше 140 символов", а не это лучше не полагаться). "Чирикнуть" тоже не годится в качестве исконного эквивалента, ибо "чириканье" в русском языке в приложении к человеческой речи имеет вполне уверенное коннотирование "легковесная болтовня, треп, брехня", а твит может быть более чем серьезным и правдивым (как исключение скорее, но - может). Точно так же и с "поделиться"/"ретвитнтуть": "ретвит" определяет только один подвид "поделиться": скопировать все, не добавив ничего от себя; а в обычном "поделиться" есть разные варианты